# Non-linear Newton-Raphson without derivative in the def?

Tags: python, math, newtons-method

I need to create a code for this specific problem 
def NewRaph2(f,g,xi,yi,Err,iter): with 2 different non-linear-equations. I know how to create a code for the Newton-Raphson algorithm when there is the derivative in the code. However, I can't put it in the definition for this one

I have my code with derivatives in it, is there a way to just modify it to find what is desired?
G1 and G2 are the functions, G11 and G21 are x partials and G12 and G22 are y partials.

```
def NewRaph2(G1,G2,G11,G22,G12,G21,xi,yi,iter,Err):

    for i in range(0,iter):
        Jac=G11(xi,yi)*G22(xi,yi)-G21(xi,yi)*G12(xi,yi)
        deltx=(-G1(xi,yi)*G22(xi,yi)+G2(xi,yi)*G12(xi,yi))/Jac
        delty=(-G2(xi,yi)*G11(xi,yi)+G1(xi,yi)*G21(xi,yi))/Jac
        x1=xi+deltx
        y1=yi+delty
        Errx=nt.absolute((x1-xi)/xi)
        Erry=nt.absolute((y1-yi)/yi)
        print('i=%2.0f x = %-7.4f y=%-7.4f Erreur en x =%-7.4f Erreur en y =%7.4f\n'%(i,x1,y1,Errx,Erry)

        if (Errx<Err) and (Erry<Err):
            solx=x1
            soly=y1
            break
        else:
              xi=x1
              yi=y1
    return solx,soly

def f(xx,yy):
    return(4*xx**2-yy**3+28)
def g(xx,yy):
    return(3*xx**3+4*yy**2-145)
def fx(xx,yy):
    return(8*xx)
def fy(xx,yy):
    return(-3*yy**2)
def gx(xx,yy):
    return(9*xx**2)
def gy(xx,yy):
    return(8*yy)
```

The formulas are as follow:

Comment: The formulas in the problem are pretty simple, is there a way with numpy to derivate them, I would know for integration, but with my limited knowledge in python, noting comes in mind for derivation. Thanks anyways, I'll try it with the secant method if I can't find anything

Comment: The first formula is this: 4x2 1 −x3 2 + 28 = 0                                                              
The second formula is this: 3x3 1 + 4x2 2 −145 = 0            I just implemented my python version of the derivatives I found by hand in the question